# How can I keep my selects on one line rather than stacking in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a form-inline class on my form and it looks great on a desktop. But when I get to the XS width EVERYTHING stacks one ontop of each other, but it's unnecessary. I only need each form-group to stack, not the form inputs inside each.

I would like to have the 3 date selects on one row and the 2 time selects on a new row below.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">        
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Passengers</label><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Departure Date / Time</label><br />
    <select class="form-control" style="max-width:100px"><option>31</option></select>
    <select class="form-control" style="max-width:100px"><option>Jan</option></select>
    <select class="form-control" style="max-width:100px"><option>2015</option></select> <strong>at</strong>
    <select class="form-control" style="max-width:100px"><option>12</option></select> <strong>:</strong>
    <select class="form-control" style="max-width:100px"><option>00</option></select>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some code making them clear each other, can you post your CSS? Just your HTML makes the selects float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap example for `.inline-form` states:

> Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for left-aligned and inline-block controls. **This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.**

The CSS they include is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

so this is why the form changes to vertical at a small resolution.
You should be able to prevent this behavior by adding the CSS:

```
.form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

(the same as Bootstrap's CSS, but without the media query)

Comment: Love it! This works perfectly and now I have great solution. Thank you!